# Reduce timeout wait on http request

Tags: .net, vb.net

How would i reduce timeout wait for this request in vb.net?

```
Dim myip As String
    myip = IPLabel.Content

    Dim request As WebRequest = _
      WebRequest.Create("http://" + myip + "/web/remotecontrol?command=116")

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

    Try
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()


        Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)

        Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)

        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)


        reader.Close()
        response.Close()

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message)


    End Try
```

If i make the request to an IP address that is not reachable at that moment an exception would be thrown only after 20 seconds, i would like to reduce that time to 5 seconds or less.

Comment: specify value for request.Timeout  property in ms  if you want to specify timeout for entire request. If you want to specify timeout only after response stream is returned and time it takes to read from that stream then specify value for request.ReadWriteTimeout property.